# Disable ssl between reverse proxy and proxied server

Tags: nginx, ssl, tomcat, reverse-proxy

I have a standard reverse proxy, with nginx and Tomcat 8.

I want nginx to handle encryption, but still inform tomcat whether the connection is secure or not.

i have

```
location /{
 listen 80;
 proxy_pass http://backend:8080;
}

location /{
  listen 443 ssl;
  proxy_pass https://backend:8443;
}
```

tomcat has the following config:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="false" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

however I am getting error

```
SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 185.3.147.237, server: backing, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:8443/favicon.ico", host: "
```

How do I tell nginx that connection to backend is not encrypted even though the address starts with https?

Comment: You could simply set the HTTPS block of Nginx to connect to `http://backend:8443` (ie without the https, port can remain the same as that's how its defined in Tomcat). Your Tomcat connector config already says that anything coming over that connector is secure due to the `scheme"https"` and `secure="true"`, so Tomcat understands its secure.

Comment: ok, except now I have trouble with redirects, as Location response header has http://, and I am stuck in redirect loops

Comment: You could make use of `proxyName` and `proxyPort` to let Tomcat know there is a proxy, this should take care of the redirect issue.

Comment: @VivekThomas that's what I ended up doing. Write it up as an answer, and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

Your Tomcat configuration has `SSLEnabled=false`. Therefore your Tomcat listens to standard HTTP on `8443` port, and nginx fails to connect to it.

I would implement this so that I would use a single upstream port to Tomcat, and set HTTP header which would contain the SSL status. Something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    proxy_set_header X-SCHEME $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://backend:8080;
}
```

This server block receives both to `http` and `https`, passes all request to Tomcat `http` backend and sets a header `X-SCHEME`, which is either `http` or `https`. Then you have the information you want in your backend.

Comment: except that spring running on tomcat couldn't care less about my custom header.